# Hours between two date time formula showing negative values

Tags: formula, case

I have written a formula to calculate the difference between two Date/Time fields,

Please find the formula

```
ROUND(24*( (5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(First_Response__c)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + MIN(5,MOD(DATEVALUE(First_Response__c)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) + MIN(1, 24/24*(MOD(First_Response__c-DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1))) ))(5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7) + MIN(1, 24/24*(MOD(CreatedDate-DATETIMEVALUE('1996-01-01 12:00:00'), 1))) )) ), 2)
```

Here I have a case whose created date is 12/12/2016 2:16AM and Firstresponse date is 12/12/2016 10:54 AM now the case response hour formula field shows me the difference between the above as -15.37 .

Please Advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
ROUND(
 /* 24 * 5 days * weeks */
 24 * 5 * FLOOR((First_Response__c-CreatedDate)/7)
  /* max 24 * 5 days */
 + MIN( 120, 
   /* days from the last week */
   24 * FLOOR( MOD((First_Response__c-CreatedDate)/7, 5) )
   /* hours difference */
   + MOD(First_Response__c-CreatedDate, 1)
 ),
2)
```